# parsing the array, in which there are arrays of objects

Tags: java, json, jsonschema2pojo, android, gson

It might be too easy but I just cannot find a solution to this. How can I  parse the array, in which there are arrays of objects?
This is my example Json

```
{  
   "status":"Ok",
   "items":[  
      [  
         "1530871200000",
         {  
            "o":"24174.11",
            "c":"24320.92",
            "h":"24350",
            "l":"24170.08",
            "v":"61.75980004"
         }
      ],
      [  
         "1530878400000",
         {  
            "o":"24322.74",
            "c":"24308.52",
            "h":"24632.36",
            "l":"24300",
            "v":"98.16061555"
         }
      ],
      [  
         "1530885600000",
         {  
            "o":"24367.16",
            "c":"24450",
            "h":"24450",
            "l":"24290.13",
            "v":"56.9420044"
         }
      ],
      [  
         "1530892800000",
         {  
            "o":"24427.73",
            "c":"24413.87",
            "h":"24542.69",
            "l":"24356.91",
            "v":"81.64183111"
         }
      ],
      [  
         "1530900000000",
         {  
            "o":"24472.81",
            "c":"24275",
            "h":"24538",
            "l":"24215.72",
            "v":"75.40993175"
         }
      ],
      [  
         "1530907200000",
         {  
            "o":"24275",
            "c":"24420",
            "h":"24461.61",
            "l":"24249.42",
            "v":"53.58580779"
         }
      ],
      [  
         "1530914400000",
         {  
            "o":"24420",
            "c":"24437",
            "h":"24538.11",
            "l":"24293.91",
            "v":"53.87857788"
         }
      ],
      [  
         "1530921600000",
         {  
            "o":"24437",
            "c":"24413.82",
            "h":"24449.11",
            "l":"24411.13",
            "v":"0.48062667"
         }
      ],
      [  
         "1530928800000",
         {  
            "o":"24414.05",
            "c":"24494.37",
            "h":"24505.7",
            "l":"24293.9",
            "v":"15.75597079"
         }
      ],
      [  
         "1530936000000",
         {  
            "o":"24500",
            "c":"24486.86",
            "h":"24500",
            "l":"24459.25",
            "v":"2.34557367"
         }
      ],
      [  
         "1530943200000",
         {  
            "o":"24486.86",
            "c":"24482",
            "h":"24531.43",
            "l":"24434.04",
            "v":"60.734314"
         }
      ],
      [  
         "1530950400000",
         {  
            "o":"24549.38",
            "c":"24444",
            "h":"24583",
            "l":"24406.13",
            "v":"56.25116508"
         }
      ]
   ]
}
```

"1530871200000" this value is random. Previously, when I had the Json to parse with an object {} I just used the POJO class + gson. Now I can't cope with parsing the array, in which there are arrays of objects. Lower I paste the Pojo that I wanted to control with this Json.

Chart.java

```
private void Chart(String cryptoCurrency, String fiatcurrency, int resolution, long from)
{
        BitBayInterface3 charts = BitBayInterface3.retrofitAPI3.create(BitBayInterface3.class);
        Call <Chart> call = charts.chartApi3(cryptoCurrency, fiatcurrency, resolution, from, System.currentTimeMillis());
        call.enqueue(new Callback <Chart>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call <Chart> call, Response <Chart> response)
            {
                List <ItemClass> itemClasses = new ArrayList<>();
                for (Map.Entry<String, ItemClass> entry : response.body().getItems().entrySet()) {
                    itemClasses.add(new ItemClass(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().getO(), entry.getValue().getC(), entry.getValue().getH(), entry.getValue().getL(), entry.getValue().getV()));
                }
                Log.e(TAG, "CHART SERVICE response isSuccessful " + " body " + itemClasses.size());
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call <Chart> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e(TAG, "CHART SERVICE " + t);
            }
        });
}
```

ItemClass.java

```
public class ItemClass {
private String o;
private String c;
private String h;
private String l;
private String v;
private String timestamp;

public ItemClass(String timestamp, String o, String c, String h, String l, String v)
{
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
    this.o = o;
    this.c = c;
    this.h = h;
    this.l = l;
    this.v = v;
}

@JsonProperty("o")
public String getO() { return o; }
@JsonProperty("o")
public void setO(String value) { this.o = value; }

@JsonProperty("c")
public String getC() { return c; }
@JsonProperty("c")
public void setC(String value) { this.c = value; }

@JsonProperty("h")
public String getH() { return h; }
@JsonProperty("h")
public void setH(String value) { this.h = value; }

@JsonProperty("l")
public String getL() { return l; }
@JsonProperty("l")
public void setL(String value) { this.l = value; }

@JsonProperty("v")
public String getV() { return v; }
@JsonProperty("v")
public void setV(String value) { this.v = value; }

public String getTimestamp() {
    return timestamp;
}

public void setTimestamp(String timestamp) {
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
}
}
```

ItemElement.java

```
public class ItemElement {
public ItemClass itemClassValue;
public String stringValue;

static class Deserializer extends JsonDeserializer<ItemElement> {
    @Override
    public ItemElement deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        ItemElement value = new ItemElement();
        switch (jsonParser.getCurrentToken()) {
            case VALUE_STRING:
                value.stringValue = jsonParser.readValueAs(String.class);
                break;
            case START_OBJECT:
                value.itemClassValue = jsonParser.readValueAs(ItemClass.class);
                break;
            default: throw new IOException("Cannot deserialize ItemElement");
        }
        return value;
    }
}

static class Serializer extends JsonSerializer<ItemElement> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(ItemElement obj, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
        if (obj.itemClassValue != null) {
            jsonGenerator.writeObject(obj.itemClassValue);
            return;
        }
        if (obj.stringValue != null) {
            jsonGenerator.writeObject(obj.stringValue);
            return;
        }
        throw new IOException("ItemElement must not be null");
    }
}
}
```

ChartConverter.java

```
public class ChartConverter {
// Serialize/deserialize helpers

public static Chart fromJsonString(String json) throws IOException {
    return getObjectReader().readValue(json);
}

public static String toJsonString(Chart obj) throws JsonProcessingException {
    return getObjectWriter().writeValueAsString(obj);
}

private static ObjectReader reader;
private static ObjectWriter writer;

private static void instantiateMapper() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    reader = mapper.reader(Chart.class);
    writer = mapper.writerFor(Chart.class);
}

private static ObjectReader getObjectReader() {
    if (reader == null) instantiateMapper();
    return reader;
}

private static ObjectWriter getObjectWriter() {
    if (writer == null) instantiateMapper();
    return writer;
}
}
```

retrofit2 void

```
private void Chart(String cryptoCurrency, String fiatcurrency, int resolution, long from)
{
        BitBayInterface3 charts = BitBayInterface3.retrofitAPI3.create(BitBayInterface3.class);
        Call <Chart> call = charts.chartApi3(cryptoCurrency, fiatcurrency, resolution, from, System.currentTimeMillis());
        call.enqueue(new Callback <Chart>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call <Chart> call, Response <Chart> response)
            {
                try {
                    Chart data = ChartConverter.fromJsonString(new Gson().toJson(response.body().getItems()));
                    Log.e(TAG, "CHART SERVICE response isSuccessful " + " body " + data.getItems().length);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call <Chart> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e(TAG, "CHART SERVICE " + t);
            }
        });
}
```

and Interface

```
public interface BitBayInterface3 {

String BASE_URL_API3 = "https://api.bitbay.net/rest/";

Retrofit retrofitAPI3 = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL_API3)
        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();


@GET("trading/candle/history/{crypto}-{fiat}/{resolution}")
Call <Chart> chartApi3(
        @Path("crypto") String crypto,
        @Path("fiat") String fiat,
        @Path("resolution") int resolution,
        @Query("from") long from,
        @Query("to") long to
);}
```

And this rejects the following error "com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 27 path $.items[0][0]"

I need an object in the form of chart.get(0).getObjectKey(); or chart.get(0).getC();

The only method that does not work entirely is to replace ItemElement[][] with Map, but then I cannot get to a single element or to the key of an object that is generated randomly.

@EDIT 13:19

It now works without ItemElement or ChartConverter. I don't know if this is the best solution, but until I find a better one, I will apply it.

Answer (score 3):

`items` is an array of array of either `String` or `ItemClass`, so its type must be one of the following, since `Object` is the only common type of `String` and `ItemClass`:

- `Object[][]`
- `List<List<Object>>`
- Other combination of above

---

*Opinion:* It's a badly designed JSON. If you could change it, you should do one of the following:

- Change inner array to object:

  ```
  "items":[  
        {  
           "a":"1530871200000",
           "b":{  
              "o":"24174.11",
              "c":"24320.92",
              "h":"24350",
              "l":"24170.08",
              "v":"61.75980004"
           }
        },
  ```
- Change array-array to a `Map` aka a JSON object (assuming first value is unique):

  ```
  "items":{
        "1530871200000":{
              "o":"24174.11",
              "c":"24320.92",
              "h":"24350",
              "l":"24170.08",
              "v":"61.75980004"
        },
  ```

Comment: I have tried your way and it still doesn't work, the error that is displayed, it is 
"java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $".
So the POJO class is bad ? in retrofit2 my call looks like this 
Call <List<List<Object>>> chartApi3();

Comment: @Mich Edit the question and show what you've done. I was saying to change field `items` from type `ItemElement[][]` to type `Object[][]`.

Comment: Json is already parsing well, thank you for your help ;) However, I cannot access individual objects. I need this response.body().getItems().get(0).getC();

Comment: @Mich Now that `items` is a `List<List<Object>>`, why would you think `getItems().get(0).getC()` would work? `getItems()` returns `List<List<Object>>`, so `get(0)` returns `List<Object>`, and `List` does have a `getC()` method. The inner list has two elements, and the second is the `ItemClass`, so you need to add `get(1)` and cast, i.e. `((ItemClass) response.body().getItems().get(0).get(1)).getC()`

Comment: rejects the following   error  'java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to com.bitbay.mbart.bitbayapp.dataModel.chart.ItemClass'